# When testing is it possible to get a reference to a local variable without using @ViewChild?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, local-variables, ng-template

I don't believe adding `@ViewChild('greatTemplate) ref;` is a good solution, just to satisfy a test. There has to be a way to get a `local variable` reference via the TestBed.

```
<button (click)="doSomething(greatTemplate)>

<ng-template #greatTemplate>Hello, World.</ng-template>
```

The only thing I've been able to find via the angular.io documentation is [here in this section "debugelement"](https://angular.io/guide/testing#debugelement-1) where it explains you can dig into the fixtures debugElement references to look for `local variables` however this seems to only capture components or native DOM elements and not the `ng-template`.

Comment: why do you need to get reference to local template? you can always mock it, right?

Comment: It would be possible, but in this case I have functional code inside the template. For example doSomething() would show a section (the ng-template content) and there is a button in the ng-template that would hide the section. I would want to test this. My other solution I have today is to re-write the logic and not pass in the template ref via html file but use viewchild and refer to it that way.

Comment: `<ng-template>` will be removed from the HTML before it is rendered to the DOM (see the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template)). That is why you cannot query for it as explained in the debugElement section of the docs - the element is no longer there when you are querying for it. What are you trying to accomplish with setting the local template variable?